# Subclassing UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I want to subclass `UIActionSheet` so I can add blocks API.

I want to subclass so I can still enjoy the "self retained" behavior of the action sheet.
I prefer it than creating an object that will hold a `UIActionSheet` as an instance, because then I will need to hold a reference to that object, so it won't be released.

**So my question is, can I subclass the `UIActionSheet` (will Apple allow that)?**

I just not sure cause I saw that in the `UIActionSheet` class reference:

> Subclassing Notes:
>    UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor
>   should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet
>   with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you
>   can create your own and present it modally with
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:.

Comment: I agree with @tanzolone on the idea that you can't subclass it. It states that right in the question that you asked. You can find numerous ways of creating custom UIAlertView and action sheets online as tutorials. A start is to create a subclass UIView perhaps.

Hope this helps

Comment: Well you could just wrap around the actionsheets/alertview, like many have done: https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets, https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIActionSheet-Blocks and http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/block-based-action-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. If you subclass UIActionSheet your app is likely to be rejected when sent to the Apple App Store. You need to implement your own custom action sheet if the UIActionSheet doesn't suit your needs as it is. The same applies to UIAlertView.

This is clearly **[stated in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**:

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: Why do you think that?  What rule would you be breaking?  How would they know?

Comment: I have subclassed UIActionSheet numerous times and have never been rejected for that

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting negative votes here - it is clearly stated by Apple and it is definitely forbidden in iOS 7: "UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:". @rp90 the fact that you've been lucky does not mean it is correct doing it.

Comment: @AaronBrager - I've updated my answer with the reference to the Apple documentation. It is definitely forbidden in iOS7.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I still think there is a LOT of room between "not designed to be subclassed" and "likely to be rejected" / "forbidden in iOS 7".

Comment: @tanzolone You're just plain wrong I'm afraid - it's definitely not **forbidden** anywhere. What I suspect Apple want to discourage (not forbid) is updating the view hierarchy, but that's not what OP is proposing. Many people have done just what he wants to do without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can subclass `UIActionSheet`. I've written (and used) my own subclasses of this and `UIAlertView` for exactly the reason you state.

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed

…doesn't say you **can't** subclass, just that it's not designed for that.

As long as you're not using private methods, you'll be fine!